# Html.Raw giving error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am getting following error:

```
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

When I try to use:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>  Html.Raw(item.ChangesMade))
```

in my asp.net MVC 3 view.

Can you please suggest correct syntax ?

Comment: You don't need Html.Raw there at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**
You can't use the HTML.DisplayFor helper TEMPLATE with an HtmlString like that which is returned from Html.Raw.

Instead, assuming your item.ChangesMade contains raw HTML that is useful try just

```
@Html.Raw(modelItem => modelItem.ChangesMade)
```

OR (more likely) if ChangesMade is just a value then use the Html helper:

```
@Html.TextBox("NameOfTextbox", modelItem.ChangesMade)
```

The easiest way for simple properties is to use the Templated Helpers (EditorFor, TextboxFor, etc) because they will utilize any DataAnnotation attributes you've used in your model classes -- especially important with built-in validation!

For example:

```
public class MyModelClass
{
    [Required("The name field is required")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So you could use the Templated Helper if item.ChangesMade is a simple type and can be expressed by a (Textbox, Checkbox, Textarea, etc).

```
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.ChangesMade);
```

You might also use in combination with built-in validation:

```
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.ChangesMade)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => modelItem.ChangesMade)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a display template taking a simple string as a model

Something like:

```
@model string
@{
 <span>@Html.Raw(Model)</span>
}
```

Call it DisplayMyHtmlString and put it under Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates

In your view just use the EditorFor helper:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ChangesMade, "DisplayMyHtmlString", "Name")
```

It should work, I use a similar Template for an EditFor.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Html.Raw there? Just write like this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>  item.ChangesMade)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing.  I'm assuming you used the view builder inside of Visual Studio to create your view and ended up with something like:

```
.
.
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.field1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.field2)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.field3)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
.
.
```

After playing around with it for a bit I just ended up replacing:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.field1)
```

with:

```
 @Html.Raw(item.field1)
```

And it output the desired result for me - an HTML encoded field

Granted you also want to put in security measures against people throwing script tags and the like in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can just omit both **DisplayFor** and **modelItem =>**,  so:

```
@Html.Raw(item.ChangesMade)
```